# Create custom script in package.json that commits and pulls before starting server NextJS

Tags: reactjs, git, shell, package.json, react-scripts

I want to create a custom script in my package.json that will perform the following actions:

1. git init and git add .
2. prompt the user for a commit message from the terminal, if the user enters an input, that input will be used as a commit message and the commit will be executed. If the user presses enter, the a default commit message will be used to execute the commit
3. pull from the remote origin after committing then start the server.

The essence is to automate a process of pulling changes regularly from the remote before making new changes when working in development mode

Answer (score 0):

I was able to do this using simple-git, an npm package. Check it out at [Simple git](https://www.npmjs.com/package/simple-git)